# Why can't I see any console logs for my iPod?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, console, ipod-touch

My iPod touch is connected to my mac. I want to see console logs of the iPod.

I have xCode connected, and the console.app.

Why can't I see console logs?[image]

Comment: isn't there supposed to be a green 'light' when device is connected?

Comment: Sure! You know know more than i do!! Why is my light orange???

Comment: Martin R is right: you have to add this device as your development device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow light indicates that Xcode does not recognize your iPod as development device. There should be a "Use for Development" button in that case.